# Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm writing my very first unit test based on the official Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests)

However, when trying to use their example I'm getting the above mentioned error when I try to test. I'm looking around but can't find anything about this particular error.

My attempt:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { VService } from './vservice';

fdescribe('VService', () => {
 let VServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<VService>;

 beforeEach(() => {
   const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('VService', ['getAll']);

   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     // this fixed an issue which is why i added it
     providers: [{ provide: HttpClient, useValue: spy }]
   });

   VServiceSpy = TestBed.get(VService);
 });

 it('should be created', () => {
   expect(VServiceSpy).toBeTruthy();
 });

 it('#getAll should return stubbed value from a spy', () => {
   const stubValue = [
     {
       id: '1',
       name: 'Repairs',
       number: '000000001',
       address: '1 Test Rd. Tampa, OH 44442',
       phoneNumber: '111-111-1111',
       emailAddress: 'test@email.com'
     }
   ];
   // here is the issue
   VServiceSpy.getAll.and.returnValue(stubValue);

   expect(VServiceSpy.getAll()).toBe(stubValue, 'service returned stub value');
   expect(VServiceSpy.getAll.calls.count())
     .toBe(1, 'spy method was called once');
   expect(VServiceSpy.getAll.calls.mostRecent().returnValue)
     .toBe(stubValue);
 });
});
```

I think it's an issue with my service returning an observable? I thought that was pretty standard though. There's nothing special about my service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close.  To test a service, you need to add that service to the providers array.  So change this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  // this fixed an issue which is why i added it
  providers: [{ provide: HttpClient, useValue: spy }]
});
```

to something like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    VService,
    { provide: HttpClient, useValue: spy }
  ]
});
```

Note: you can do a spy for HttpClient as you have it set up, but also look into `HttpClientTestingModule` which is well [documented here](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests).

Comment: It took me a while to get my head around it but this is exactly what I needed.